# bootstrap and jquery modal failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with Bootstrap and jQuery, and I've got the modal content working fine using the text attributes to trigger the open.

However, I am trying to close the open modal window from another script and I get the error that `modal is not defined`:

```
modals.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function(anonymous function) @ modals.js:94dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
modals.js:86 Object {__ob__: Observer, __v-for__1: Fragment}
```

The code looks like this:

```
$('#mymodal').modal('hide');
```

The loading order of the js files is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/modals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How is modal not defined if the modal window works properly from the `data-toggle="modal"` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of banging my head, this was due to another version of jQuery being imported through a bower installation that I wasn't aware of. Once I knew where to look it was an easy fix to remove this duplicate jQuery and the site works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Probably other script rewrites bootsrap modal function `$.fn.modal`

If it true you need to resolve conflict:

```
var bootstrapModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
$.fn.bootstrapModal = bootstrapModal;
$('#mymodal').bootstrapModal('hide');
```